# ProtoBufFormatter missing in .netcore package

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-standard

i am trying to convert this code from .net 4.5.2 to .net standard

```
string requestURIAction = ....;
MIObjectSetType objectSet = new ....;
CancellationToken cancelToken = new....;
this.Formatter = new ProtoBufFormatter();

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(requestURIAction, objectSet, this.Formatter, cancelToken);
```

I replaced the nuget package WebApiContrib.Formatting.Protobuf to the equivalent .net standard version - WebAPiContrib.Core.Formatter.Protobuf

but ProtoBufFormatter does not exists in WebAPiContrib.Core.Formatter.Protobuf
How can i rewrite it?

Comment: ProtoBufFormatter [inherits from MediaTypeFormatter](https://github.com/WebApiContrib/WebApiContrib.Formatting.ProtoBuf/blob/9c3e061a70f0154728cf684ac258b9ae350e8825/src/WebApiContrib.Formatting.ProtoBuf/ProtoBufFormatter.cs) which doesn't seem to be available in .Net Core

Comment: What was your solution to this ?

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternative method that I found here:
https://damienbod.com/2017/06/30/using-protobuf-media-formatters-with-asp-net-core/

First install WebApiContrib.Core.Formatter.Protobuf 2.0 nuget package

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddControllers().AddProtobufFormatters()
}
```

Then you can call the server and de-serialise using the following code instead of the ProtoBufFormatter

```
static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Table[]> CallServerAsync()
{
    var client = new HttpClient();

    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "http://localhost:31004/api/tables");
    request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-protobuf"));
    var result = await client.SendAsync(request);
    var tables = ProtoBuf.Serializer.Deserialize<Table[]>(await result.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync());
    return tables;
}
```